# Implementing a sort of key-value pair (not essentially a HashMap) in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the best way to implement the following scenario in Java:

A sort of key-value pair mechanism, but it looks like this:

```
param1 + param2 + param3 -> output1   
param1 + * + !param3 -> output2  
param1 + text containing value param2 + * -> output3  

'*' => any parameter  
!param => any value other than this parameter  
text containing value 'param' => any data which contains the value 'param'. ex: aaaaa,bbb,param,ccc or aaaparambbb
```

In my view, a HashMap makes it difficult to implement this type of mapping. What is the best way to implement some mapping like this ?
I was also considering putting these in an Oracle table and trying to write a procedure, but there might be a better way in Java.

Comment: You need to implement exactly this procedure or is it just a sample of a general mechanism? If it is the latter, then it seems like a task for a database, and there is no reason to reinvent a weel and do this strictly in java.

Comment: Hi Rogach,this is just a sample of a general mechanism. My only concern is that I need to connect to the database and wanted to find out if there's a simpler way in Java itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of achieving this could be a triple nested hash-map. Or a hashmap of hashmaps of hashmaps.

The psuedo-code for querying would be something along the lines of this:

```
//You would call this method to search. 
string query(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    // The essence of the logic is, if you give a value for param3,
    // then it will do the subquery of the hashMap that param3
    // is the key of, if you don't supply a value (or provide the wildcard)
    // it will search all the different hashmaps of the parent hashmap.
    // See below for an example
    if param1 != WILDCARD
    then subquery1(hashmap[param1], string param2, string param3);
    else for each x in hashmap, subquery1(x,string param2, string param3)
}

string subquery1(hashmap[hashmap[]] maps, string param2, string param3)
{
    // The essence of the logic is, if you give a value for param2,
    // then it will do the subquery of the hashMap that param2
    // is the key of, if you don't supply a value (or provide the wildcard)
    // it will search all the different hashmaps of the parent hashmap.
    if param2 != WILDCARD
    then subquery2(maps[param2], string param3);
    else for each x in maps, subquery2(x, string param3)
}

string subquery2(hashmap[] maps, string param3)
{
    if param3 != WILDCARD
    then return maps[param3]
    else for each x in maps, return maps[param3]
}
```

Obviously you need to define if multiple values are allowed to be returned and how you wish to resolve this.  Also you need to determine if param 3 is nullable?  The problem statement is pretty vague but I've done my best to answer what i think your problem is.

An example would be if you have added the following values to your hashmap.
key1, key2, key3 = value1
key1, key2, key4 = value2
If you searched key1, *, key3 you would get value1 returned.
If you searched key1, *, * you would get value1, and value2 returned.

**Update:**
When you call query("key1", "*", "key3");

Since param1 is valid (not wildcard) we call subquery1(hashmap["key1"], "*", "key3");
Before we get to subquery1 though, hashMap["key1"] is evaluated, but it returns another hashmap,
lets call this hashmap hashmap2[]. So subquery1 is actually called with (hashmap2[], "*", "key3");

Now we are in subquery1.
Since param2 is "*", we then iterate through all the values of hashmap2[],
for each hashmap3[] in hashmap2[], we call subquery3(hashmap3[], "key3");

At this point since param3 is valid, we call hashmap3["key3"] and we get value1 returned;

Comment: @Steven: Can you add more comments to code, I am trying to understand what actually is happening and having hard time.

Comment: I added some comments to the code, if you have more questions ask.

Comment: @Steven: I am still having hard time to understand instruction flow, can you explain instruction flow with an example. Actually I want to understand the logic and learn from your approach.

Comment: I updated it again.  I think i have given you the execution plan that you are asking for, but ask if you need more. Let me know if you need more detail, also if you have an application for this it might be helpful to post more details, or even a question on its own so I or others can address your situation more directly.

Comment: I do not have an similar application or problem at hand right now but I have never worked with multiple hashmaps and so this problem triggered my interest and I wanted to learn from your approach. This is my first time trying to understand multiple hashmaps and so I might be facing some issues more particularly I am not able to understand ` hashMap["key1"] is evaluated, but it returns another hashmap,
lets call this hashmap hashmap2[]. So subquery1 is actually called with (hashmap2[], "*", "key3");` line, my query might sound stupid but its just that I want to gain some knowledge about hashmap

Comment: Actually I want to understand how does multiple hashMap call work in general, I guess than I would be in better state to understand this approach.

Comment: Any recommendation on what should I get started with ?

Comment: Well a hashMap is just a data collection type that can contain any object type, including another hashMap.  I am more familiar with C++, so i will give an example from C++, but I'm sure the java syntax wouldn't be much different.  To declare the triple level hashMap in c++ your syntax would look something like this "hashMap<string,<hashMap <string, hashMap<string, valueType> > > tripleLevelMap;"  That is why when hashMap["key1"] is evaluated, you are returned a hashMap, which is then what will be passed into subquery1.

Comment: To understand the "That is why when hashMap["key1"] is evaluated" part you need to look at the programming languages parameter passing mechanisms, which typically evaluate parameters before passing them to the method.  To help with understanding the other part, try to think of it as a hashmap, that has a key and a value. The value just happens to be another hashmap.  Start with understanding a double nested hashmap, and once you understand that it will be very easy to go to the triple nested hashmap.

Comment: @Steven: Thank you for your advice, I appreciate your time and efforts explaining this. I will dig little more on this and post any questions I have later.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for the comments. I will check it out. @Rachel: Thanks for asking those questions. It helped me too :)

Comment: If you provide more detail on the problem you are facing there might be a better solution.  I have only ever had a need for nested hashMaps once, but that could have also been solved other ways when i think about it in retrospect.  If you give us more, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you have/need is an NFA where your params are the symbols.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite-state_machine

Comment: Thanks z5h. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to represent the values. This will allow you to quick and easily navigate your structure and also quickly manage your *any* and *not* conditions. You can find one [here](http://code.google.com/p/trie/).

Comment: Thanks Cornelius. But a trie is used to represent characters at each node of the tree. Can we have strings too ?