# Custom key for a HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need to map a `[Integer, List<Integer>]` key to an `Integer`. I have considered the following approaches and am struggling to figure which is most beneficial, given that speed is key.

WHY I NEED THIS?

There is a 2D array. Each row is the number of lines going out of a station. Each row contains the lines originating from a subway. So, subway stations are numbered 0,1,... All rows have the same number of elements (same number of lines originating from all stations). 0th index of a row gives the destination on taking the 0th line. 1th index of a row gives the destination on taking the 1th line,... The rth element of the list for station k, gives the station directly reachable by taking line r from station k. Now, suppose you are lost at one of the stations. Independent of which station you are at, if you take a certain combination of paths, you will arrive at a common station. This is called a meeting path. I need to find if, for a given subway configuration, there is a meeting path possible. Eg. For `subway = [[2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1], [1, 0]]`, taking line1 then line0 from any station, results in ending up at station2. So [1,0] would be a meeting path. 
I have generated a set of paths, that would look like [[0],[1],[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,1],...]. I have to traverse the path from each station to see if I end up at the same station for all the stations. Say, we consider station0, and am considering path[0,0,1]. I would already have traversed the path [0,0]. Instead of traversing that portion again, I can use whatever result I had after traversing [0,0] and take line1 from that point, to end up at my new destination. This is why I need to cache ([startStation, pathList], destination). Moreover, if this way of searching for a meeting path doesn't work for say, 8 degrees of paths, we need to check if closing down a certain station will result in a meeting path. This is more so, why I want to use a [startStation, pathList] as a key. Link to full problem statement is at the end of the post.

First approach: Create a new `unmodifiableList` with the value at the 0th index as the aforementioned `Integer` and the rest as the `List<Integer>`. I would use this `unmodifiableList` as the key.

Second approach: Create a new `unmodifiableList` with the value at the 0th index as the aforementioned `Integer` and the 1st index as the hashCode for an unmodifiable copy of `List<Integer>`. I would use this `unmodifiableList` as the key. [Thilo correctly noted in the comments that this approach would cause collisions].

Third approach: [Nested Map] Create a mapping from an `Integer` to another `HashMap` that maps from `List<Integer>` to `Integer`. [Similar to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743731/implementing-a-sort-of-key-value-pair-not-essentially-a-hashmap-in-java)]

Fourth approach: Make an object with `Integer` and `List<Integer>` as fields, and override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. This would serve as the key.

I feel the third approach is the simplest, and would make for the most readable code. I am struggling to weigh the pros and cons with respect to all 4 designs. Speed is key here.

This is with reference to a question on the Google Foobar challenge [[problem](https://github.com/dray92/Google-Foobar/blob/master/Dont_Mind_The_Map.java)]

Comment: If you need a Map, why dont you use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`? Access time is `~O(1)`

Comment: Second approach will not work in the presence of hash code collisions.

Comment: "speed is key" -- how is it key? Are you sure a Java Map is what you want in this case?

Comment: @fge Foobar times out after a certain point. So, I realized I need to cache some data to speed up the processing time. I would need a dictionary data structure since I need a (key, value) combination to be able to cut the processing time from O(n) to O(1).

Comment: @Prashant I need a (Integer-List<Integer>) as the key and Integer as the value.

Comment: @Thilo I see what you mean. Thanks you so much for your input. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Maybe if you explain why you think you want to use a complex object containing an integer and a list as a map key we can better help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison I understand what you said. I have added the problem statement.

Comment: Are you familiar with *dynamic programming*?

Comment: @ruakh Yes, I am. Am I not using principles of DP in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would favour using a custom class, you can make it more readable by using your IDE to generate getters, setter, `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString()` methods.

Note: using a HashMap instead of an object has a much higher overhead and make your program more difficult to profile later.

Comment: I would be immensely grateful if you could provide me a reference.

Comment: @DebosmitRay on how to use your IDE or why creating lots of objects is more expensive than creating one?

Comment: On how I could implement a custom class to mimic mapping abilities. I understand how using a bunch of HashMaps would create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @DebosmitRay you would to know how to create a class in Java which has two fields, like an `int` and a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: I understand I need an object with Integer and List<Integer> as fields. Now, to use this as a key, the issue would be coming up with a hashCode function that would not cause a bunch of collisions. I was thinking of using the product of the hashCodes of the fields. Do you think something can go wrong with that approach?

Comment: @DebosmitRay Like I suggested, I would use the **IDE to generate getters, setter, equals, hashCode and toString() methods**, unless you have some very specific requirements.

Comment: Mr Lawrey: Thanks a lot for your help. I will, of course, go by all the points you have made [here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2013/10/unique-hashcodes-is-not-enough-to-avoid.html?q=hashmap) and [here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2015/09/an-introduction-to-optimising-hashing.html).

Comment: @DebosmitRay Unless you have millions or billions of entries, you are unlikely to need to tune your hashCode strategy. Often giving the Map more memory e.g. reducing the load factor (if you need to) will give you much the same effect with less effort.

Comment: Ah! That clarifies a bunch. Thanks, Mr. Lawrey!